# Как подключиться к MS SQL 2016 из PHP (всё на одном ПК, локально происходит)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Установил настроил драйвер вот по этой инструкции:
https://php.ru/forum/threads/kak-ja-nastraival-php-mssql.41096/

Вопрос №1: Работает ли этот PHP драйвер для подключения к версии MS SQL 2016?

Вопрос №2: Где в MS SQL взять имя сервера + логин/пароль пользователя под которым я в итоге буду стучаться в MS SQL?

Вот данные что MS SQL сказал после установки, но как-то их недостаточно:
[image: Данные MS SQL]

Comment: И что сказал MS SQL после установки? У меня ссылка почему то не открывается.

Comment: откройте SSMS залогиньтесь под sa, пароль которого вы добавляли при установке. Создайте БД, добавьте пользователя, настройки этому пользователю права доступа к этой БД. имя сервера `localhost`, или `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: для работы с PDO надо установить [расширения PDO для апача (видимо v.4.0) а также драйвера ODBC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

Comment: Какая именно версия SqlServer стоит? В строке соединения `Server=` должно быть `.\SQLExpress` или `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb` для версий SqlExpress и LocalDB соответственно.